# WPF Multiple Validation.ErrorTemplate s depending on the type of error

Tags: wpf

I am just starting out with WPF and im playing around mvvm and with styling.

I have a text box bound to my view model field FirstName.
FirstName is a required field and has a max length.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Too long")]
    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("FirstName");
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("CanSave");
        }
    }
```

I have added some styles to show up when there is an error

```
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               FontSize="14pt"
                               Margin="-15,0,0,0" 
                               FontWeight="Bold">*</TextBlock>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="controlWithError"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},          Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background"       Value="{StaticResource ErrorBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So now i have a nicely formatted box that has a red background and a red asteriks when there is an error.  When you start typing this is removed, and then when the length hits 20, and there is an error again, this turns back to the validationtemplate.

My question is, has anyone implemented different templates for different types of error.

What i would like to do is for every property that is required to have a red asteriks to begin with - no red background.  Then when they have typed something in, and the required field error has gone, the asteriks should go.

But the other error validaiton should maybe show an exclamation mark, and a red background.

Anyone?